# MySQL Many to One design decision

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have a posts table, and each post can have an associated list of images ( a gallery ).  Currently 
I am storing the image data in a separate table.  I'm thinking about serializing the data and putting it
together with the posts.

The reason for this is that I want to run a query that produces a list of posts and it's associated gallery images.

My question: is it okay to de-normalize in this way, and if not, what would be your solution?

Answer (score 0):

As a rule, de-normalizing is not a good idea (remember the "Relational" in Relational Database), though there are occasions that justify it.  In this case, I don't see any good reason to de-normalize in order to store a *list* of binary information.  If it were me, I'd be sticking to a one:many relationship between the posts and the images, just like the database is designed for, and be sure to insure that you're optimized indexing, etc.

Comment: if I keep it normalized, then if there are 5 images per post and I want to create a query that lists 20 ( posts + images ), i'll get 100 rows in the join. is this common practice and I should just use application code to sort it out?

Comment: You can do it that way, or select just the posts, then within a loop of those select the images for the current post...I suppose there are many ways of doing it, but de-normalizing is not generally the way to go as it inevitably will bite you down the road.

Comment: doing selects inside a loop would generate 21 queries for each request in the above example, which is what I wanted to avoid. It seems over kill.  So the only solutions I came up with was 1. de-normalizng, 2. do sorting in the application.  I wasn't sure which is the more appropriate solution.

Comment: I guess I miss understood....if you're wanting to show all images for all posts on one page?  Even if that's the case, I'd still be inclined to normalize and use a JOIN....at the end of the day this isn't a compelling reason to de-normalize IMHO.